# Thunderbird lost password help please

Tags: thunderbird

I recently had a malware attack, and my computer was wiped, losing all information including my Thunderbird account.

I have installed a fresh copy of Windows 10, and a new download of Thunderbird, but the setup is asking for my Thunderbird password (which I now don't have).

Is there any way to retrieve my login password for my Thunderbird account?

Comment: Thunderbird is an email client, correct? Your password should be your email account password. So you should recover your password from your email provider.

Answer (score 2):

- Assuming that you are talking about the Primary Password to protect the application.  I would suggest that you uninstall thunderbird (and clear all data etc).  Then re-install it.
- I have never used the above, it is possible that the default password for the primary password is your Windows login password.
- If you didn't have a primary password, then the password its referring to is the password for your email account.  If its a GMail account for example, then its the password you use to access GMail.  If you have forgotten that then follow the recovery process for Gmail on a browser.